# Can virtualmin read in Debian Virtual Hosts?

Tags: debian

I've got an existing system that I've mainly been administering from the command line with an occasional use of Webmin for creating users, etc. I just installed and with some fiddling got virtualmin configured. Is there any way I can get it to notice and create virtual servers for the existing sites set up in Apache with homedirs under /home ? They all have associated user and group accounts.

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can go to `Add Servers > Import Server` and there is an import form for pre-existing domains on the server.

> Import Virtual Server
>
> This form can be used to bring an existing domain on your system under
>   the control of Virtualmin. Mailboxes and aliases for the domain name,
>   any existing Apache virtual server and DNS domain will be
>   automatically detected. You can also enter the name of a database to
>   associate with the domain, if any exist.
>
> The password field should be filled in with the administration user's
>   current password, if you know it. Virtualmin needs to know each
>   virtual server's password, for use when setting up MySQL or PostgreSQL
>   databases in future.
>
> If the domain has a private IP address, you must enter it at the
>   bottom of this form and indicate that the IP is used exclusively by
>   this site. For name-based websites or domains that only host email,
>   the default IP import settings will work fine

I haven't personally tried this before since I always install virtualmin on clean servers, but it may worth trying it out :)